# How to write a nested for loop in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 pyspark dataframes in my environment:

df

```
y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10 y11 y12
12 rf 22 34 32 54 54 21 43 544 545 332
12 ed 23 34 23 53 23 23 22 434 342 432
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ... ... ...
```

df_filtered

```
y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10 y11 y12
12 rf 35 34 32 54 54 21 43 544 545 332
12 ed 99 34 23 53 23 23 22 434 342 432
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ... ... ...
```

y3 is a timestamp column and my problem statement is: 
to pick a timestamp i.e. y3 from df_filtered for a given y1. 
extract 10 values prior to that time stamp from df.
calculate quantile ranges for y7 to y12.
check if df_filtered values are within quantile ranges.
any one value is out mark that row in df_filtered as outlier else real.

expected output

```
y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 y10 y11 y12 status
12 rf 22 34 32 54 54 21 43 544 545 332 real
12 ed 23 34 23 53 23 23 22 434 342 432 outlier
.. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ... ... ... ......
```

if i consider the data in pandas dataframe format. following for loop is working:

```
low = 0.25
high = 0.75
list1 = []
for i in range(len(df_filtered)):
 x = df[(df['y3'] >= df_filtered.loc[df_filtered.index[i],'y3']-10) & (df['y3'] < df_filtered.loc[df_filtered.index[i],'y3']) & (df['y1'] == df_filtered.loc[df_filtered.index[i],'y1'])]
 y = x.quantile([low,high])
 #y2 is automatically removed as y2 was a text column hence quatile not calculated
 y = y.drop(['y1','y3','y4','y5','y6'],axis=1)
 for j in y.columns.values:
    t1 = []
    t = "real" if y[j][low] <= df_filtered.loc[df_filtered.index[i],j] <= y[j][high] else "outlier"
    t1.append(t)
 t2 = 'outlier' if 'outlier' in t1 else 'real'
 list1.append(t2)
df_filtered['status'] = list1
```

Comment: can you mention more realistic data-frames. The ones you mentioned are same

Comment: i have given few rows as the dataframes are in sql and i am working in cloud environment 
i dont have a realistic copy